# Update column in snowflake sql and set one duplicate row =1 and the rest to 0

Tags: sql, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have got the following table:

```
Col1 Colb ID Mark
1    2    1  Null
2    4    1  Null
2    3    2  Null
2    3    1  Null
2    3    2  Null
2    3    3  Null
```

I want to Mark all the rows where there is duplicate IDs. What I want to do is to set the Column Mark for one of the duplicate IDs to 1 and rest to 0.

So like this for example:

```
Col1 Colb ID Mark
1    2    1  1
2    4    1  0
2    3    2  1
2    3    1  0
2    3    2  0
2    3    3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using windowed functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col1 INT, colb INT, ID INT, Mark INT)
AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
 (1,    2,    1,  Null)
,(2,    4,    1,  Null)
,(2,    3,    2,  Null)
,(2,    3,    1,  Null)
,(2,    3,    2,  Null)
,(2,    3,    3,  Null);
```

Warning! This table does not have true PRIMARY KEY and the "first" row per `ID` is chosen in underterministic manner(i.e., `ORDER BY 1`).

Query:

```
SELECT COL1, COLB, ID, 
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Mark
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]